# How do I do something when I press a key on the keyboard?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I want to make a basic game using Windows Forms.

I want to end the turn of a player when I press <kbd>Space</kbd> on the keyboard. I've tried using `getch()`, but it isn't a good solution because the character has to be entered in the debug window, as it isn't constantly polling for a key press.

A basic pseudocode example of what I need is something like this:

```
if(PlayerPressesSpace)
{ 
    //end turn of player (I've got this bit figured out)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a Windows Forms GUI app, each `Form`, and every child `Control` inside of it, has its own [`KeyDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keydown), [`KeyUp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keyup), and [`KeyPress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress) events that you can assign individual handlers to as needed.

Or, you can handle all key events within an entire Form instead of on a per-Control basis, by setting the Form's [`KeyPreview`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview) property to `true` and then using the Form's `KeyDown` event. See [How to handle keyboard input messages in the form (Windows Forms .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/input-keyboard/how-to-handle-forms) for more details.

Comment: I can see KeyDown and KeyUp but there are no signs of KeyPress

Comment: Look again, it has to be in there.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I use on space press because i get the error propriety not valid

Comment: @FOLINIDIEGO which property? Please edit your question to show the code that is not working for you.

Answer (score 1):

In a WinForms Form, you can override [ProcessCmdKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey) of the Form container, to pre-process Key presses **before** they're dispatched to the destination. See also the Docs about this.

This allows to intercept keys that are used to activate default action, as the <kbd>TAB</kbd> Key, used to move the Focus to the next Control in the `TabIndex` hierarchy.
You can then perform any action required before the default action is performed, or suppress the Key, returning `true` when the conditions you have set are met.

It can also be used to generate special actions when combinations of Keys are pressed.

```
protected: 
virtual bool ProcessCmdKey(Message %msg, Keys keyData) override { 
    if (keyData == Keys::Space) { 
        /* do something */ 
        // Suppress the Key press, the message is not sent to the destination recipient
        return true;
    } 
    // Otherwise, let the message pass through
    return Form::ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData); 
}
```

If you just need to *intercept* Keys that don't have special uses, as the aforementioned <kbd>TAB</kbd> Key, or some other Key that is processed by specific Controls for their internal use - so the Parent may or may not be notified - you can set the `KeyPreview` property of your Form container to `true` and handle the `KeyDown` event, as mentioned in [Remy Lebeau answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69005318/7444103).

When `KeyPreview` is set to `true`, the Form class sets a state, `formState[FormStateKeyPreview]`; its [ProcessKeyPreview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.processkeypreview) override checks this state and behaves as the `ProcessCmdKey` override in most cases.

Answer (score -1):

I can only think of

```
if(Console::ReadKey(true).KeyChar == ' ') {
    ...
}
```

[Console.ReadKey Method Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=net-5.0)

Comment: This is in a Windows Forms app, not a Console app.

Comment: I've tried that makes my program crash probably making useless steps forever